# How to add customer account login to custom module page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, login

I have custom module that registers customers for an event/product. 
I created a page that displays the registration form from my module.

The link to the registration page is in the footer.

When a user clicks on the footer link, I don't want users to be able to see the registration form if they aren't logged in.

So I need them to first see the login/register screen and only once they successfully login/register they should get redirected to the page with my module's registration form.

screenshot:
 [image]
In attached image its should show form fields after login/register
magento1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-login-form-on-home-page-in-magento/

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i tried this one ...but its not that much descriptive

Comment: Already solved, refer the link  
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178776/how-to-call-customer-login-form-in-the-custom-module-action-magento-2